# incorrect cheksum for freed object

Tags: c, unix

No consigo encontrar el fallo de memoria; dependiendo del tamaño del BUFFER_SIZE el código se ejecuta correctamente o no.
La función ft_strdup crea memoria en la variable que devuelve, por eso libero la variable estática.

> a.out(62418,0x118e555c0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fc09d004800: probably modified after being freed.
>   Corrupt value: 0x4d4d4d4d4d4d4d4d
>   a.out(62418,0x118e555c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

```c
    #include "get_next_line.h"

    char    *ft_newstatic(char *aux, char *l, char **line)
    {
        char    *temp;
        int     leng;

        leng = ft_strlen(l);
        temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (leng + 1));
        ft_strlcat(temp, l, ft_strlen(temp) + (leng - ft_strlen(aux)) + 1);
        *line = ft_strdup(temp);
        free(temp);
        free(l);
        l = ft_strdup(&aux[1]);
        return (l);
    }

    int     get_next_line(int fd, char **line)
    {
        static char *l;
        char        *buffer;
        size_t      nbytes;
        char        *aux;

        l = (!l) ? ft_strdup("") : l;
        buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
        if (!buffer || fd <= 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0 || !line)
            return (-1);
        while ((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
            l = ft_strjoin(l, buffer);
            if ((aux = ft_strchr(l, '\n')) != NULL)
                return (((l = ft_newstatic(aux, l, line)) != NULL) ? 1 : 1);
        }
        if ((aux = ft_strchr(l, '\n')) != NULL)
            return (((l = ft_newstatic(aux, l, line)) != NULL) ? 1 : 1);
        *line = ft_strdup(l);
        free(l);
        free(buffer);
        return ((nbytes < 0) ? -1 : 0);
    }
```

Comment: "*freed object probably modified after being freed*" Eso suena a haber liberado dos veces el mismo puntero.